# Where can I ask questions about what frameworks exist that solve a special problem?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I saw that questions get downvoted at Stack Overflow when they are like "Which java frameworks provide RPC functionality?", because they are off-topic.

Is there a Stack Exchange community where I legitimately can ask such a question?

Comment: Possibly http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but I'd read their help and about pages carefully first.

Answer (score 4):

You can ask on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). However:

- Ask for a singular, not a plural. Your question has to be narrowly scoped enough to describe a single desirable framework
- State *very* specific features that you want to be present in the framework
- State things that would be 'nice to have' *as* nice to have - in a secondary list. Make sure your must-have stuff is above it
- Give as much detail about how you envision using it as possible, so that you *really* narrow the number of possible answers
- Please, don't ask for 'best' or 'good' - folks aren't going to recommend the 'worst' or 'bad' :)

It could very well be that you needs can be met, but it might take a bit of work on your part. Answers will go into this. It could also be that nothing available meets your specific needs, so make sure to put *only* what's absolutely essential as essential.

In short, your job is to limit (as much as possible) the number of answers that would actually apply.

Just look around prior to asking, I'm *pretty* sure a few Java framework questions have been asked. If they're totally different from what you hope to get out of something, it's fine to ask.

And yeah, you better [read this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and make *sure* you follow the links it contains :)